# window.open image resize jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window.open

hi i am trying to create html popup of an image of perfect size but it only works second time.

for example, when you click an image, it will open without perfect size and if you close it and open it again, it works!

please debug my code:

```
$(function() {
    $("a.popup3").click(function(){

        var asrc = $(this).attr("href");

        var image = new Image();
        image.src = asrc;

        window.open(image.src,"Image","width="+image.width+",height="+image.height);
        alert(image.src+"adfaSDF"+image.width);

        return false;   
    });
});
```

and the html is like:

```
<a class="popup3" href="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Eccles_leaving.jpg">
   <img class="alignnone wp-image-196" src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Eccles_leaving-300x200.jpg" alt="Eccles_leaving" width="220" height="147">
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to open the window inside of a load function,

```
$(function() {
    $("a.popup3").click(function(){
        var asrc = $(this).attr("href");
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = asrc;
        image.onload = function() {
            window.open(image.src,"Image","width="+image.width+",height="+image.height);
        };
        return false;   
    });
});
```